# I am trying to block a kind browser with RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, blocking

this is what identifies this browser in the apache log

"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"

what should the correct syntax be ?

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"

Answer (score 0):

Don't make an exact match on the *user agent* because it can vary slightly and the test will then fail for the same browser version. To exclude Firefox version 31, match just on the substring as

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} \ Firefox/31 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Now, the browser will receive a *403 Forbidden* error.